# How can I continue running my script after I have caught an error?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to monitor a mongo database, if my script loses connection the server I need it to send an email. However in the code I have so far the error is caught and kills the script.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://server:port/";

async function admin() {
    try {
        const client = MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true })

        if (!client) {
            // Send email
        }
    } catch(err) {
        if(err == "MongoNetworkError") {
            console.log("no connection")
            send_email_function(); //this function does not run in the case of no connection           
             }

        console.log(err)
        // Send email
    }
}

admin();
```

Comment: is `send_email_function` reachable inside the `admin` function?

Comment: @Zoti well that's in my question, if server is down `send_email_function()` will not run

Comment: @zoti it is not reachable

Comment: what is the `console.dir(err)` can you post it here?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty it didnt log anything

Comment: does the admin function being executed at all?

Comment: @zoti yes because it logs an error for the no connection to db

Comment: which one? the `console.log("no connection")` or the `console.log(err)`?

Answer (score 0):

`try` and `catch` aren't able to catch asynchronously thrown errors. A simplified version might look something like:

```js
try { setTimeout(() => { throw new Error("I won't be caught") }, 10) }
catch (ex) { // this won't work }
```

You'll want to register a listener on the connection AND use `await` with the initial connection creation:

```js
let client;
try {
  client = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
  client.on("error", (err) => handleError(err));
} catch (err) {
  handleError(err)
}
```